# Find all points in $\mathbb{C} $ in which the function $f(z) ={\rm Log}(z-1)*\tan(z) $ is not defined or not analytical.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all points in $\mathbb{C} $ in which the  function $f(z) ={\rm Log}(z-1) *\tan(z) $ is not defined or not analytical. What is the character of isolated singularities?

I am pretty much stuck. I guess I should look at the domain of the function. Any hint helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: What is the domain of $\operatorname{Log}(w)$? of $\tan(z)$?

Does $\operatorname{Log}(w)$ have any isolated singularities?

What can we conclude about the singularities of $\tan(z)$? about the isolated singularities of $f(z)$?